# I came directly to my residence from the airport

Tags: word-usage

Why directly in 1st sentence is wrong whereas right in 2nd sentence, because directly is adverb and in 1st it tells about come(verb). So which rule follows here-

- I came *directly* to my residence from the airport.
- I phoned him *directly* I heard the news

Comment: Both sentences are grammatical.

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence is not wrong, it means you did not stop anywhere on the way.

There are two uses of "[**directly**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/directly)" here. From the Oxford Dictionaries

> **1** Without changing direction or stopping.
>   *they went directly to the restaurant*
>
> **1.1** At once; immediately.
>   *I went directly after breakfast*

Comment: But my book says, in 1st it should be direct

Comment: [**Direct**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/direct) can be used as an adverb, but that does not make **directly** incorrect. In this link is the example *"Austrian Airlines are flying direct to Innsbruck again"*.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think that the usage of directly is wrong in:

> I came **directly** to my residence from the airport.

I think that both sentences are perfectly correct, and i might well say either.